# Gradle автоматически создает ненужный класс

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

При запуске нового проекта в IntelliJ Idea, gradle создает класс HelloCounter и HelloApplication

Как исправить build.gradle файл так, чтобы он автоматически не создавал ненужный мне класс?

Файл buils.gradle при этом выглядит следующим образом

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.example.demo1'
    mainClass = 'com.example.demo1.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: Что это за классы, что в них содержится? Добавьте в вопрос.

Comment: Это не столь важно. Для меня главное – навсегда изменить build.gradle файл. Чтобы при будущих запусках он не выполнял эти комады. Можно ли это как-то сделать в настройках IntelliJ Idea?